In my Android app Fcm triggering token refresh hugely without any app install from past 2 days
Previously we used to get fcm push token refresh around 2000 a day. Now it's increased to 500k a day. Due to this uninstall are to increased.
Anyone faced this problem and resolved the issue? Most of tokens are registered 90 days back.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
